# Cakephp how to add multiple view files within a single controller using ajax

Tags: jquery, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-ajaxhelper

I have a controller called User.i write three functions in that controller, ie; function1,function2,function3 each functions have corresponding view file in the View/User folder.my problem is , in my function1.ctp file i create a left menubar using jquery. there are three menus in that menubar,when i click each menu, i want to load the content of function1.ctp ,function2.ctp function3.ctp with the help of ajax request to the controler .how we can do this? is this possible..? if anybody can help me..please reply

Comment: You need to show some effort, what did yo try? What isn't working? Where is your code? StackOverflow if not meant to have other people write your code *for you*. Read the [faq] to understand what kind of questions you should ask.

Comment: @thaJeztah i dont want any code, i want to know only how to approach this problem to find a solution, if u understand my question and you know bout this, then give me the route..how we can solve this problem, what approach i should use. thats all. iam a newbee in cakephp and jquery and ajax,but i created something only with my effort..please support me .dnt dowmvote ..

Comment: @thaJeztah using jquery and ajax it is possible? if it is possible, then give me the way how can i do this, i dont want code...give me a approach to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible - AJAX defines it as possible.

If you already have the three functions set-up and see them rendering their views when you go to `example.com/yourcontroller/functionName` then you're almost tehre.

What you need to do now on the client side is when a user clicks on a main-menu - load the submenu, right? Well attach a javascript click function callback to the clicked HTML item and when that event occurs call the server via AJAX.

You will need to ask yourself "What do I need to return from the server - HTML or JSON?"
In the first case - when you receive the HTML data back just put it in the DOM where you want it to be. In the second case you will need to process the JSON and build HTML or whatever.

This was the answer, now some advice.

Do you absolutely really, really need to use AJAX for menus? 
Do they change that often?

Remember: **1 AJAX call == 1 request to the server**
Are your sub-menus really that data/change intensive that you need to load them like this?
If your menus change based on the user's location (in the site) or user actions for example, ok you can use this, but otherwise you're killing a mosquito with a bazooka!
You should try to keep the data exchange as low as possible, gzip the server returns, etc. etc. This solution could be an overkill for this situation.

Comment: your answer is very helpful for me.your answer do not solve my problem.see, my UI is designed in such a way that 4Horizontal menu tabs in the top, and three vertical menu tab corresponding to that, which is placedin the left side.i created these three vertical tabs using jquery.when i click tab1,then in the right side , content of the tab2,tab3 are hidden. these three tab coontent are three controller functions,and each have corresponding view file. my doubt is how we can load each view in that content section using ajax call so that initialy when the page is loaded i dont want to load al cont

Comment: How exactly did you create these tabs - jQuery UI Tabs or what? When do you want to load the content for each? Initially or on some kind of event? I alsready explained how to do this on an event.

Comment: i created that tabs using Jquery UI,for example when i click tab1 it will call some controller function and load the corresponding view ,but my requirment is i want to load different views inside one view according to user click on these tab,

Comment: @SibinF Could you defina what you mean eactly with "i want to load different views inside one view according to user click on these tab"?
If you have some reusable content that you need to render in many views used View Elements.

Comment: i know little bit about element,i dont want to use element.see, i have a controller PostsController and a function view() and a view.ctp in the view/Posts folder.in the UI side when i click a tab menu the default layout is loaded ,and in the $content_for_layout section the view.ctp is displayed inside a Div element.are u getting? then my problem is , i have one another controller and corresponding one function and one add.ctp . when i click another tab menu that Div element is updated by new add.ctp how we can do this???

Comment: I "am getting" since I do know and understand the internal workings of Cake.
As I explained previously - when "you click another tab menu" make an AJAX request to the server. This request should go to your "another controller"'s add action : `example.com/another/add/`.
In this controller action set `$this->layout = 'ajax`. This will prevent Cake from rendering the main layout (since the ajax layout is empty). Catch the response in your java script and replace the contents of your div with it. That is it! If you want a more technical explanation ask.

Comment: now i got the idea..thanx a lot..how we can make ajax request? when i click the tab what url assigned for that tab? how the controller perform that request.. i dont know about how to send ajax request...can u post a simple example in ur answer(please edit ur answer if u can)it will help all the people.

Comment: Are you using a javascript library - such as jQuery or plain javascript?